# Error: [ng:cpws] in formController with deep watching - angularJS 1.8.0

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple scenario with a formController which has child controls (input and text area). When I use a deep watcher (with `objectEquality` equals true) to check changes in the whole form, I'm getting the `Error: [ng:cpws]`

This is the basic code (using the latest angularJS):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-forms-simple-production</title>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="formExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form" name="formContent">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /></label><br />
    <label>Description: <textarea ng_model="user.description"></textarea></label><br />
  </form>
  <pre>user = {{user | json}}</pre>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.master = {};

      $scope.$watch(() => $scope.formContent, (newValue, oldValue) => {
        console.log('new ', newValue);
        console.log('old ', oldValue);
      }, true);

    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the issue in console is:

```
angular.js:15697 Error: [ng:cpws] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2-build.2468+sha.9b3b6f7f7/ng/cpws
    at VM469 angular.min.js:7
    at e (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at c (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at e (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at c (VM469 angular.min.js:12)
    at e (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at c (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at e (VM469 angular.min.js:13)
    at Ia (VM469 angular.min.js:15)
    at m.$digest (VM469 angular.min.js:153)
```

I don't fully understand which attribute within the form object is causing the issue. According to angularJS documentation, this could be caused because of cyclical and self-references

The live code in plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/B9n7GAPkZvzsFbKN?preview

Comment: As additional info, I realized that when I change the angularJS version to 1.6.0 or further, keeping the objectEquality as true, the error appears. However, when using a lesser version (e.g. 1.5.0) keeping the true in the watcher as well, the error does not appear. I was looking at the breaking changes btw 1.5.0 and 1.6.0, but I see no clear reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this issue is explained here: [Unintended breaking change when passing ngModel as a binding](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15833)
Basically, (since 9e24e77) we put the scope on the NgModelController instance, so it is no longer possible to copy such instances (which happens under the hood when $watching).